# Disable JButton focus border

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a problem with JButton in Java. Basically, I want to disable the button's border (the button is added to JDesktopPane ).

Here is my code :

```
 JButton j = new JButton("BUTTON");
 j.setIcon(icon1); //icon1 : icon//
 j.setFocusable(true);
 j.setContentAreaFilled(false);
 j.setBounds(90, 20, 130, 30);
 dtp.add(j); //dtp : JDesktopPane//
```

It could let the border disappear like in this image:

[image]

But when my mouse is clicked (not moved around) into the button, there is a "dot" border around the button, like this:

[image]

So, how could I set the button so that when I don't move the mouse around the button area, it's still set like the first image, but when I move the mouse around, there's a square around the button (with a light-blue background)?

Comment: *"let the border disappeared like this image"*  That looks very non-intuitive.  What *else* are you doing to confound & confuse the poor end user?

Comment: So, which words do u think  best in this case? Btw, English isn't my first language.

Comment: I was referring to the borderless button as being 'non-intuitive', not what you wrote.  What you wrote is quite clear.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 120):

That is not border. It's focus. You can remove it using:

```
jButton1.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Comment: this solution not worked with ButtonGroup and JRadioButton

Answer (score 11):

This may be old thread, but I solved mine with 
`button.setFocusable(false)`

hope it helps for those whose still looking for some answer.
cheers.

Comment: Important to note that this is the correct default behavior only for ToolBars. In Visual Studio with Windows Forms a ToolStrip has TabStop set to false by default. Use my UI fix above to get rid of the dotted borders on Toolbar buttons and ToggleButtons which never have them in Windows with or without focus.

Comment: Relevant answer for `Component`s other than `JButton` (how I ended up here)

Answer (score 4):

After digging I have come up with a better solution. This is also a common UI bug in GTK applications on Windows, one of them being GIMP. It greatly annoys me so I wanted to find a better fix global fix than setting it on every control manually.

The workaround sets the color for the focus on all the common controls that it's not supposed to occur to transparent. I went and tested extensively with Windows Forms in Visual Studio. Toolbar buttons and ToggleButtons should never have the dotted border even when focused. Toolbars are supposed to be setFocusable(false); by default as they are in Windows. Every other control should have the dotted border as in Swing, but only when being focus cycled.

```
        // Removes the dotted border around controls which is not consistent with Windows
        UIManager.put("Button.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("ToggleButton.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        // ways to remove it from other controls...
        UIManager.put("CheckBox.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("RadioButton.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("Slider.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        // figure out combobox
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think doing this with usual `JButton` is a good idea. If nothing, it will not show similar in different platforms ( Mac & Linux) in case you plan to show this button in different platforms.
For all practical purposes `button.setFocusPainted(false);` should take care of your current requirement.

Consider using an extended `JLabel` with button like behavior(with action listeners) to avoid behavior differences.

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setFocusPainted(false); //To don't paint borders while 
                              //JButton is in focus.

button.setBorderPainted(false);//To don't paint JButton's borders.
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this can help you out [Remove border](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/89165)

or maybe this

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
yourButton.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

Comment: When i set "Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
yourButton.setBorder(emptyBorder)"; it gave me the normal button without any effect.