# Swing: remove focus border from dialogues' buttons

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton, uimanager

I wonder how can I remove this grey border from buttons in dialogues? [image]

For simple JButtons I found a solution - just use `button.setFocusPainted(false);`
But is there a simple way to perform the same for all buttons in all dialogues?
I tried to look through UIManager properties, but it seems that there are no suitable parameters there.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"..how can I remove this dashed grey border from buttons in dialogues?"*  Why are you intent on making yet another unusable GUI?  Those dashes are there to show focus.  Leave them be.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Well, you're right - removing focus border affects usability, but I can offer two arguments. 1) I use message dialogues with only one button in my application (first picture in my post was taken from Oracle's website), so I suppose focus border is useless in such case. 2) I find this border really inappropriate, may be it would be better to draw it only around whole button, not around button's text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- from `JButtons API` you can to use `JButton.setFocusable()` and  with `JButton.setBorderPainted(false);`
- from `UIManager` have to override key (valid for whole JVM instance)

.

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.put("Button.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

- I'd to suggest to change `Color` with `transparency` (4th paramater in a.m. code) to another more decent `Color`, otherwise you can't to see focus for any of `JButtons

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
JButton.setFocusPainted(false)
```

Comment: Simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

Here's a global fix so you don't have to do it manually for every control. From my other post: [Disable JButton focus border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361658/disable-jbutton-focus-border/35146492#35146492)

```
        // Removes the dotted border around controls which is not consistent with Windows
        UIManager.put("Button.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("ToggleButton.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        // ways to remove it from other controls...
        UIManager.put("CheckBox.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("RadioButton.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        UIManager.put("Slider.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));

        // figure out combobox
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.focus", new ColorUIResource(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```