# Removing lines around button after it's clicked in Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, lines

I have a JButton in Java(Swing):

[image: Button]

After the click I get this line around the button:

[image]

How do I remove these lines?

Comment: This behavior is by design.  (it's called focus)

Comment: [look this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422642/swing-remove-focus-border-from-dialogues-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button.setFocusPainted(false);` is the right solution!