# How do you remove the selection box in the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jbutton

In any program, or at least most, when you select a button or anything, there is a selection box made of lines which are made of dots.

How do you get rid of that box?

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a button with an image, no contentFill, no borders, and it looks very awkward when selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the button or component non-focusable by calling its `setFocusable(...)` method:

```
myButton.setFocusable(false);
```

---

**Edit**
... or maybe even better:

```
myButton.setFocusPainted(false);
```

This way the component can still get the focus if need be, but just doesn't show the focus border.

Comment: Also please have a look at mKorbel's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422861/522444).

Comment: Thank you so much, I apologize for asking an already answered question, I didn't know how to call it while looking for an answer